# How to replace JSON text value in the textarea by giving input to the text box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have JSON in the textarea. I have to replace the JSON key value by giving input to another textbox.

Below is my JSON ...I will replece the value of name and zoom:max, zoom:min with the value that I will put in the text box.

```
{
              "deployment": {
                "name": "Leather Cap",
                "zoom": {
                  "max": 400,
                  "min": 170
                },
                "scale": 6.75,
                "gradient": "false",
                "optional": {
                  "fov": 25,
                  "logos": "true",
                  "autoload": "true",
                  "hideInfo": "true",
                  "transparent": "true",
                  "disablePanning": "true",
                  "hideFullscreen": "true"
                },
                "rotation": {
                  "x": 0,
                  "y": 0,
                  "z": 0
                },
                "textures": {
                  "albedo": "albedo.jpg",
                  "preview": "preview.png",
                  "aoIntensity": 0.05,
                  "normalScale": 1,
                  "metalnessValue": 0.65,
                  "roughnessValue": 0.85
                }
              }
           }
```

Here is my JS: 
function updateFunc(){

```
 const textField= document.getElementById('myText').value;
 const x=JSON.parse(textField);

 const fname = document.getElementById('tname');
 const newName = JSON.stringify(x).replace(deployment.name, test);
 x.deployment.name = JSON.parse(newName);

 const zMin = document.getElementById('tZmin');
 const newZmin=JSON.stringify(x).replace(deployment.zoom.min, test1);
 x.deployment.zoom.min = JSON.parse(newZmin);

 const zMax = document.getElementById('tZmax');
 const newZmax=JSON.stringify(x).replace(deployment.zoom.max, test2);
 x.deployment.zoom.max =JSON.parse(newZmax);
```

}

HTML:

```
<textarea name='fname'rows="1" cols='1'id='tname'></textarea><br>
            zoom:<br> min:<br>
<textarea name='zoomMin'rows="1" cols='1'id='tZmin'></textarea><br>
            max:<br>
            <textarea name='zoomMax'rows="1" cols='1'id='tZmax'></textarea><br>
 <button type='submit' onclick="updateFunc(); return false;">update JSON</button><br>
```

My code doesn't work. When I click the button 'update json'. It refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this! I wanted to use your json and edit your code, but I was unable to track some of the DOM elements that you have used in the above code. I hope this is what you are looking for. If not, then do share a feedback though.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "deployment": {
    "name": "Leather Cap",
    "zoom": {
      "max": 400,
      "min": 170
    }
  }
};
document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

function updateFunc() {
  let name = document.getElementById('tname').value;
  let Zmin = document.getElementById('tZmin').value;
  let Zmax = document.getElementById('tZmax').value;

  jsonObj.deployment.name = name;
  jsonObj.deployment.zoom.min = Zmin;
  jsonObj.deployment.zoom.max = Zmax;

  document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
}
```

```html
<textarea name='fname' rows="1" cols='1' id='tname'></textarea><br> zoom:
<br> min:<br>
<textarea name='zoomMin' rows="1" cols='1' id='tZmin'></textarea><br> max:
<br>
<textarea name='zoomMax' rows="1" cols='1' id='tZmax'></textarea><br>
<button type='submit' onclick="updateFunc(); return false;">update JSON</button><br>

<div id="myText"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you much for your solution. It works perfectly.